# How can i get the date of month from a date in Jquery/javascript from input type

Tags: javascript, jquery

When looping through a input's of type date I cannot extract the current date with it meaning when I apply getDate() on the date I get a random number.

```
jQuery(".JESUSISKINGANDIWILLBEINTHESCHOOLOFDAVIDHOGAN input[type=date]").each(function(){
var date = new Date(jQuery(this).val());
}
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and perhaps create a runnable snippet showing your issue?

Comment: first read  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849

Answer (score 0):

It's quiet difficult to say what you are trying to accomplish, however I did my best to aid you in your search for the solution.

In the example presented below, I am looping through all data fields if smth was changed.

Here is JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/8zfxhpuL/31/

```
<form id="date-test" action="">
  <input type="date" id="1">
  <input type="date" id="2">
  <input type="date" id="3">
  <input type="date" id="4">
  <input type="date" id="5">
  <input type="date" id="6">
  <input type="date" id="7">
  <input type="date" id="8">
  <input type="date" id="9">
  <input type="date" id="10">
</form>
```

```
const $dateFields = $('[type="date"]')

console.log($dateFields)
$('#date-test').on('change', function(event) {
    console.log(`Chosen value: ${ $(event.target).val() }`)

  loopDateFields()
})

function loopDateFields() {
    $dateFields.each(function(index, singleField) {
    console.log(`The field no#${ index } has the following value: ${ $(singleField).val() }`)
  })
}
```

If you need more specific help, please make your question more detailed. Right now it is really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here.